# PyThouch custom loss function: "one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation"

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, pytorch-geometric

I am making a GNN that tries to solve Power Flow problems. For it I have been thinking of using a custom loss function called "physics_loss".
The problem is that when using this loss function the call for loss.backwards() causes an error

> Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
> one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor []], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2832; expected version 2831 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
> File "...\GNN_OPF\src\train.py", line 60, in train_batch
> loss.backward()
> File "...\GNN_OPF\src\train.py", line 33, in train_model
> epoch_loss += train_batch(data=batch, model=gnn, optimizer=optimizer, criterion=criterion)
> File "...\GNN_OPF\src\main.py", line 48, in main
> model, losses, val_losses = train_model(arguments, train, val, test)
> File "...\GNN_OPF\src\main.py", line 58, in <module>
> main()
> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor []], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2832; expected version 2831 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

The error shows up in the train batch function, when using the physics_crit = True:

```
def train_batch(data, model, optimizer, criterion, physics_crit=True, device='cpu'):
    model.to(device)
    th.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = model(data)
    if physics_crit:
        loss = physics_loss(data, out)
    else:
        loss = criterion(out, data.y)
    loss.backward() #Error pops up when this line is called
```

I assume that this error is cause in by the physics_loss function:

```py
def physics_loss(network, output, log_loss=True):
    active_imbalance = output[:,0] # th.zeros(output_r.shape[0])
    reactive_imbalance = output[:,1]#th.zeros(output_r.shape[0])
    resist_line_total = th.multiply(network.edge_attr[:, 0], network.edge_attr[:, -1])
    react_line_total = th.multiply(network.edge_attr[:, 1], network.edge_attr[:, -1])

    denom = th.add(th.multiply(resist_line_total, resist_line_total),th.multiply(react_line_total, react_line_total))
    conductances = th.div(resist_line_total , denom)
    susceptances = th.multiply(th.div(react_line_total, denom),-1.0)
    for i, x in enumerate(th.transpose(network.edge_index, 0, 1)):
        angle_diff = th.sub(output[x[0],3] , output[x[1],3])

        active_imbalance[x[0]] =th.sub(active_imbalance[x[0]],th.multiply(th.multiply(th.abs_(output[x[0], 2]) , th.abs_(output[x[1], 2])), th.add(th.multiply(conductances[i], th.cos(angle_diff)) , th.multiply(susceptances[i], th.sin(angle_diff)))))
        reactive_imbalance[x[0]] = th.sub(reactive_imbalance[x[0]],th.multiply( th.multiply(th.abs_(output[x[0], 2]), th.abs_(output[x[1], 2])), th.sub(th.multiply(conductances[i], th.sin(angle_diff)) , th.multiply(susceptances[i], th.cos(angle_diff)))))

    if log_loss:
        tot_loss = th.log(th.add(1.0 , th.sum(th.add(th.multiply(active_imbalance, active_imbalance), th.multiply(reactive_imbalance, reactive_imbalance)))))
    else:
        tot_loss = th.sum(np.abs(active_imbalance) + np.abs(reactive_imbalance))

    return tot_loss
```

I have made an effort to use all torch functions for every operation, however in my debugging attempts I have reason to believe that is is the active and reactive imbalance calculations that cause the error, as in a previous version of the code I used Tensor.detach() in those operations and it did not cause errors (since it was not take for back propegation).

I tried using only torch operations for everything (in previous versions when using inbuilt operations such as: +,*,/. I got the same error, but with different "versions") and I did some test with detaching the gradient at different points in order to try and find out where the error was cause.

Comment: `add`, `multiply` and `div` all mutate the tensors in-place. Consider making a copy of sorts.

Comment: That will not allow the loss back propegation to learn from the loss, I already tried making a copy of the output tensor, and that did run but since it was detached it did not learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

Many pytorch operations have an "in-place" version. In-place operations are denoted by an extra `_` on the operation name. For example, `.abs` makes a copy, `.abs_` is in-place. Your code's use of `th.abs_` is probably causing the error.